# asp.net core mvc navigation not working with angular 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

Here is the below mvc routing template

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    template: "{*url}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

I am using angular 2 routing. Here is my **service.login.ts**

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginViewModel } from "../ViewModel/Login.ViewModel";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private heroesUrl = "Account/Authentication";//ApplicationRootUrl("Login", "Home");  // URL to web API
    private ResponseData: any;

    constructor(private loginModel: LoginViewModel, private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

    public loginHttpCall() {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, this.loginModel, { headers: headers })
            .subscribe( data => {
                this.ResponseData = data;
                this.loginModel.success = this.ResponseData.json().isSuccess;
                this.loginModel.message = this.ResponseData.json().message;
                if (this.loginModel.success) {
                    this.router.navigate(['DashBoard/Index']);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

I am able to get navigation **http://localhost:28739/DashBoard/Index**. But the content of the Index page is not loaded. The controller action method Index is not hit.However If I refresh the page with same url. The controller action method is hit and the content is loaded.

What is the issue I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `Microsoft.AspNet.SpaServices`. Install it as a nuget package and replace the `spa-fallback` with a call to the `MapSpaFallbackRoute` method (have found example [here](http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/)):

```
// when the user types in a link handled by client side routing to the address bar or refreshes
// the page, that triggers the server routing. The server should pass that onto the
// client, so Angular can handle the route
routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```